# What can I do to create an always-live HTML page?

Tags: javascript, php, html, silverstripe

I have been searching across the Web to find a solution to this:

Basically what I want to setup is a way to have an HTML page on a live production site to kept updated. This is because I have setup a SilverStripe Application as part of a graphics system (green chroma key) that runs through normal HTML.

AJAX load doesn't seem to be an option here since the load would be every 1 second or half a second to make sure the page is live.

I looked into web socket quite vaguely but the whole concept of integrating it with my project confused me entirely.

Anyone got any ideas of what could be done?

Comment: You need to keep your page updated to the maximum, and 0,5 second intervals are too slow for updates? As far as I know, websockets are the way to go if you care about high speed and low latency.

Comment: Websockets. See http://meteor.com if you want easy-to-use stuff.

Comment: I will hate your application for abusing my bandwidth and CPU-time.

Comment: You should learn about websockets. Build this part of your application separate to silverstripe they don't work well together. If you want to use silverstripe for anything build API access with SS and use the API from your websockets app.

Comment: long polling ? nevertheless would prefer websocket!

Comment: @GyroGearloose Haha! That's why I want to find a solution that will at the very least keep my bandwidth usage low.

Comment: Cheers guys for the tips! I'll check out web socket much further!!

Comment: I doubt this is possible. (Well, possibly not in comparison with "solutions" even worse). If you want my browser to send, putting the form aside,  *information* across the net as fast as possible, you'll draw my bandwidth and CPU-time as much as possible. I don't want such thing in my browser. It'll be OK on some specialized application that I have to call explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you'll need a combination of:

- **AJAX**, you'll need to never do a full page load *after* the initial Web 1.0 request.
- **Session history management**, you'll need this in order to not break the browser navigation (e.g. back/forward buttons).
- **Web Sockets**, you'll need this so when new content arrives on the server it is received by the client without first having to poll the server.

Web sockets will be the greatest challenge. I listed them in the order in which you should approach the project, in three phases.